# Update open source Ruby devkit options on docs.developer.intuit.com

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

The link for the Ruby DevKit on this page:  http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0200_DevKits/0350_Open_Source_DevKits is broken. Can we update the link to point to the [Quickeebooks gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/quickeebooks)?

The gem currently supports V2 of the QBO & QBD API with support for a majority of the functionality within both QBO & QBD. The gem is very active and new releases are constantly being pushed out, you'll notice that the most recent version was released a few days ago. The author([Cody Caughlan](https://github.com/ruckus)) and it's contributors are keeping a close eye on V3 and will be working to provide a smooth upgrade path as more details are made available.

Comment: We are working on getting updated links.